# Xamarin.Forms Android crashes on startup on VS 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My XF android application suddenly crashes with attached debugger with log

> [AssistStructure] Flattened final assist data: 4048 bytes, containing
>   1 windows, 15 views [etico.carevale] Explicit concurrent copying GC
>   freed 4954(365KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(624KB) LOS objects, 49% free,
>   2MB/4MB, paused 813us total 18.957ms [Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 111
>   objects 3846 opaque 1727 colors 111 colors-bridged 111 colors-visible
>   111 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.03ms
>   tarjan 0.88ms scc-setup 0.03ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.02ms
>   cleanup 0.08ms [Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 21.58ms
>   [Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 15.84ms, stw 17.36ms promoted
>   1302K major size: 2384K in use: 1702K los size: 1024K in use: 402K
>   [mono-rt] /proc/self/maps: [mono-rt] 12c00000-12c80000 rw-p 00000000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 12c80000-12f00000 ---p 00080000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 12f00000-13140000 rw-p 00300000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 13140000-13280000 ---p 00540000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 13280000-182c0000 rw-p 00680000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 182c0000-18340000 ---p 056c0000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 18340000-42c00000 rw-p 05740000
>   00:05 12772                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space
>   (region space) (deleted) [mono-rt] 42c05000-42c0a000 rw-p 00000000
>   00:05 13060                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large
>   object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt] 42c0a000-42c15000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:05 13061
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c15000-42c24000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13062
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c24000-42c2b000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13063
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c2b000-42c31000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13064
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c31000-42c37000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13216
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c3f000-42c44000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13067
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c44000-42c49000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13068
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c4d000-42c51000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13070
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c51000-42c58000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13071
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c5f000-42c66000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13073
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c66000-42c6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13074
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c6c000-42c70000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13075
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c7a000-42c84000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13077
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42c84000-42ced000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 13078
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42ced000-42cf1000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 11923
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42cf1000-42cf7000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 11924
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [mono-rt]
>   42cf7000-42d04000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 11925
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted) [libc]
>   Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbc in
>   tid 11317 (pool-3-thread-1), pid 11125 (etico.carevalet)
>   [etico.carevale] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0
>   native methods for
>   md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.CellRenderer_RendererHolder

if I launch application without debug it works without crashes.

I've tried on Mac and Windows - result the same.
Android studio logical shows the same log.

Answer (score 1):

There is something broken with the VS build, they are currently working on a fix. this happends for Xamarin native aswell.

Check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/515603/android-crashes-every-time-with-the-new-vs-for-mac.html) for updates on how they are doing with the fix.